# Neither useMemo nor React.memo with useContext won't work since useMemo do not memoize with the context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to memoize a component, however, because of my context, it's not being memoized and my component renders when it's not supposed to.

The Post component that i want to memoize.

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import P from 'prop-types';
import { buttonContext } from '../../contexts/App';

export const Post = React.memo(function Post(props) {
    console.log('Son rendered');

    // This line is causing the component not to memoize.
    const [counter, setCounter, search, setSearch] = useContext(buttonContext); 

    return (
        <div className="post">
            <h1 onClick={() => {
                setSearch(props.post.title);
                props.refInput.current.focus();
                setCounter((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
            }}
            >
                {props.post.title}
            </h1>
            <p>{props.post.body}</p>
        </div>
    );
});

Post.propTypes = {
    post: P.shape({
        id: P.number,
        title: P.string,
        body: P.string,
    }),
    refInput: P.object,
};
```

The context.

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import P from 'prop-types';

export const buttonContext = createContext();

export const AppContext = ({children}) => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return <buttonContext.Provider value={[counter,setCounter,search,setSearch]}>{children}</buttonContext.Provider>;
};

AppContext.propTypes = {
    children: P.node
};
```

I expect to use the React.memo to memoize my Post component correctly, and **keep** my context in the component (the line causing the issue).

Answer (score 1):

The [Updating a memoized component using a context](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#updating-a-memoized-component-using-a-context)  docs explain it clearly.

> Even when a component is memoized, it will still re-render when a context that it’s using changes. Memoization only has to do with props that are passed to the component from its parent.

> To make your component re-render only when a part of some context changes, split your component in two. Read what you need from the context in the outer component, and pass it down to a memoized child as a prop.

Besides, take a look at this issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156, there are three solutions mentioned by @dan